# Is it possible to enable some static checking for tag helpers?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

For example I can write this code in default mvc template

```
<a asp-area="" asp-route-returnUrlFoo="foo" 
   asp-controller="Account" asp-action="RegisterFoo">Register</a>
```

And it would generate incorrect url

```
/Account/RegisterFoo?returnUrlFoo=foo
```

Is it possible to throw an error when there is incorrect action name or route argument?

Comment: To be clear... `/Account` is a valid **Controller** and `/RegisterFoo` is an invalid **Action**? In addition, you want your host to **throw an exception**? Or did you mean, respond with a specific **Status Code** such as 400 - Bad Request?

Comment: @Svek Yes, RegisterFoo is an invalid Action. Yes, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fallback Method: "Universally" Handling Mismatched Controller and Actions

You can add a new route that will redirect all your invalid requests to your own specific controller and action:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // your other routes here

    routes.MapRoute(_
        name: "Fallback",
        url: "{*any}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Handler"});
}
```

In the above case, this will map everything (that is not defined) to go to `/Error/Handler`. You can modify this to meet your own requirements.

> You can read more about route templates here:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-template-reference

---

#### Alternative: Handle it per controller

Of course, there is the alternative which is to just deal with it on a controller basis instead. This approach is less generic and will allow you to create more targetted ways to deal with URI / routing errors.

#### Alternative: Check if the controller or action exists

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: I don't want for `/Account/RegisterFoo?returnUrlFoo=foo` to work, because this url is incorrect. I just want an Exception.

Comment: @ais Your controller can throw the exception.

Comment: I want an Exception when page with this url is rendering

Comment: @ais I've added another possible alternative for you that you could use. This will allow you to place the error check exactly where you want it.